# With Django, what is the best practice way to add up a specific field on each object in a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

This is how I'm currently getting a total of each object.balance in my queryset. It feels wrong. Is there a better way? (I'm struggling to explain/write the question so just see the code below :) )

```
# models.py

...

class Foo(models.Model):

    ...

    balance = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
    )

    ...
...

# utils.py

...

def get_the_total():
    objects = Foo.objects.all()

    total_balance = 0

    for object in objects:
        total_balance += object.balance

    return total_balance

...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`Sum()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Sum) built-in to Django:

```
Foo.objects.aggregate(Sum('balance'))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I noticed that will return a dictionary (I think) so to put the balance in a template I had to put `{{ foo.get_the_total.sum__balance }}` instead of `{{ foo.get_the_total }}` or in the view `{{ foo.get_the_total().sum__balance }}` or modify the `get_the_total` function to return balance.sum__balance (if balance was `Foo.objects.aggregate(Sum('balance'))`.

Comment: Oops, meant to put `return balance['sum__balance']`